# How to simulate multiply 2D array in c#

Tags: c#

My teacher asked me to multiply two n×n matrices through threads in c#.

How can I make `for` execution in parallel?

What about time complexity of code?

Is this code run in parallel or not?

```
for(int k = 0; k < n; k++)
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
{       
    K_copy = k;
    i_copy = i;
    j_copy = j;

    myThread[k, i, j] = new Thread(() => computeMultiply(k_copy, i_copy, j_copy));
    myThread[k, i, j].Start();
}
```

To multiply 2 matrices (matA and matB), we need 3 `for` in sequence methods, like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
for(int k=0;k<n;k++)
matC[i,j]=matC[i,j]+matA[i,k]*matB[k,j];
```

Consider we have n^3 processors, so we can do multiplication in parallel. So each multiplication is execute in O(1)... so we can reduce time complexity. But I don't have n^3 processors, then I have to use threads to simulate this situation. On the other hand my teacher wants to simulate running in SIMD system and simulate Parallel.For with threads!

I have registers in processors like A, B, ... but I use matP like a register of each thread.

This is the computeMultiply function:

```
 static void computeMultiply(int k, int i, int j)
    {
        matP[k, i, j] = matA[i, k] * matB[k, j];            
    }
```

Comment: That's going to be a lot of threads, assuming a non-trivial value for `n`.

Comment: you need to use `Task.Parallel` and not threads directly, in this case. Especially when you're talking about heavy computation and potentially targeting wide range of hardware - weak and strong. If you use `Task.Parallel` it wil scale and shrink gracefully, based on your system hardware and current workload. For exmaple you might look into [Parallel.ForEach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: Unless `computeMultiply` is considerably more work than starting and disposing a thread, doing this in parallel will run slower than doing it in the same thread, not faster.

Comment: Why do you need three indexes when you miltiply two nxn matix? Are there any rules as to how or what the different threads are to calculate? What does "computeMultiply" do? Is there a reason for you to save the Thread in myThread?
Pleas clarify your code and the question/task given by your professor. And please be more specific about what exactly it is you dont understand.

Comment: I'm not allowed to use parallel.for... I have to simulate a system with n^3 processors

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
   Parallel.For(0, n, i=>
   {
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        for(int k = 0; k < n; k++)
        {       
             myThread[i, j] += matA[i,k]*matB[k,j];
        }
   });
```

And if your teacher wants to laugh a little, here is some **veeery** basic implementation of Parallel.For:

```
public sealed class MyThreadPool : IDisposable
{
    private readonly Thread[] _threads;
    private readonly ConcurrentQueue<Action> _tasks = new ConcurrentQueue<Action>();
    private bool _enabled;
    private MyThreadPool(int count)
    {
        _enabled = true;
        _threads = new Thread[count];
        for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            _threads[i] = new Thread(Consume);
            _threads[i].Start();
        }
    }

    public static void For(int threadCount, int from, int to, Action<int> action)
    {
        using (var pool = new MyThreadPool(threadCount))
        {
            for (int i = from; i < to; i++)
            {
                var captured = i;
                pool.EnqueueTask(() => action(captured));
            }
            pool.WaitTillCompletion();
        }
    }

    private void Consume()
    {
        while (_enabled)
        {
            Action task;
            if (_tasks.TryDequeue(out task))
            {
                try
                {
                    task();
                }
                catch
                {
                    //can log error here if you want
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Thread.Sleep(0);
            }
        }
    }

    public void EnqueueTask(Action action)
    {
        _tasks.Enqueue(action);
    }

    public void WaitTillCompletion()
    {
        while (!_tasks.IsEmpty)
            Thread.Sleep(0);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _enabled = false;
        foreach (var t in _threads)
        {
            t.Join();
        }
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
   var threadCount = Environment.ProcessorCount * 4; //this is as much as modern processor can squese out of itself, larger values used only for IO loads, not for computation.
   MyThreadPool.For(threadCount, n, i=>
   {
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        for(int k = 0; k < n; k++)
        {       
             myThread[i, j] += matA[i,k]*matB[k,j];
        }
   });
```

Comment: I know that but my teacher doesn't accept using Parallel.for.. tnx

Comment: Added custom implementation.

Comment: can you please help me with this code, I dont understand where i can put my code?

Comment: First, I already put that for you. Second, you probably should understand that, because teacher will ask you about it. Third, make some effort at your homework, so you can actually learn something out of my answer.